# What is the value in '$_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'] used for?

Tags: php, superglobals

I can't find any mention of it [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), but there seems to be an additional entry in the `$_SERVER` superglobal named `UNIQUE_ID`? What is this value used for?

It's fairly obvious that it's a unique ID, but of what? Of the current session, script, or server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_unique_id.html

**Apache Module mod_unique_id**

> This module provides a magic token for each request which is guaranteed to be unique across "all" requests under very specific conditions. The unique identifier is even unique across multiple machines in a properly configured cluster of machines. The environment variable UNIQUE_ID is set to the identifier for each request. Unique identifiers are useful for various reasons which are beyond the scope of this document.

Comment: But what is the purpose of the ID - can we use it for anything?

Comment: Can we use this as CSRF prevention tokens?

Comment: @Sibidharan - you would have to save the unique id server side when the form is loaded, and then send it on submit and check that it is the same as the one you saved.

Comment: @Sibidharan that is entirely possible, and actually likely now that I think about it.  If you are already doing it, the simplest fix would be to salt + encrypt it to create the csrf.  Or most likely whatever language you are using has a good csrf library which is actually a much better idea

Answer (score 3):

It is the identifier for each request which is set in the UNIQUE_ID.

From [an article on devshed.com](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/_server-unique_id-questions-163269.html):

> The $_SERVER superglobal contains some elements that are available in the CGI environment.
>   Depending on the platform/web server/PHP install (cgi vs. compiled in vs. DSO etc) there can be many different variables available. You probably have the apache module "MOD_UNIQUE_ID" loaded, and apache sets this value in the CGI environment.

Also read this [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_unique_id.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is a result of the Apache module unique_id. Here is a link to the Apache doc...

http://www.itc.yorku.ca/manual/mod/mod_unique_id.html